# Trying to generalize a regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying create a regex to split a string after a second dot.

Ex.: The string `"AF23.2016.12"` should split `{"AF23.2016", ".12"}`

Till far I got the follow regex to my split:

```
"(?<=(\\p{Alnum}+)\\.(\\p{Alnum}{4}))(?=\\.)"
```

This works fine for this string, but I have to specify the length of the second part `(\\p{Alnum}{4})` but it's variant.

I tryied use `+` instead `{4}`, but if do it, the split doesn't work. Result: `"AF23.2016.12"`

How can I generalize the second part to whatever length?

Comment: Why not something like this: "[^.]*\.[^.]*(\..*)" or are there more conditions?

Comment: Is the second dot also always the last dot?  If it is, `"(?=\\.[^.]*$)"` will work.

Comment: @AlanMoore awesome, I didn't notice I could use this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try `"(?<=\\.(\\p{Alnum}+))(?=\\.)"` you get an exception saying

> Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length

(I don't know why you do not get the message with two `+`; maybe you should.) But it gives an idea what you could do to make it work: limit the length of the look-behind group. Instead of unlimited `+` use something like `{1,1000}`. This works for me:

```
"(?<=(\\p{Alnum}{1,1000})\\.(\\p{Alnum}{1,1000}))(?=\\.)"
```

(Space and or time requirements might benefit from choosing a smaller repetition limit. I haven't checked that.)

Comment: Wow. Java's regex actually supports variable length lookbehinds? That is exceedingly rare.

Comment: I guess now I  understand why not use unlimited `+`. Thanks. `{1, 1000}` is a good solution. I will use 100 only lol

Answer (score 1):

Instead of split it is better to use a match using captured groups:

```
(\w+\.\w+)(\.\w+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG9hY6/1)

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\\w+\\.\\w+)(\\.\\w+)" );
```

Then use `Matcher` API to get both captured groups.

Comment: I needed to split, not match

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do what you want:

```
^([A-F0-9]+?\.[A-F0-9]+?)\.([A-F0-9]+)$
```

Or with your `\\p{Alnum}` syntax:

```
^(\\p{Alnum}+?\.\\p{Alnum}+?)\.(\\p{Alnum}+)$
```

I'm not sure in what context you're using this regex. The results here will put the first and second parts into `\1`, `\2`.

Comment: This will not work if the first character is already a dot. Not sure if that's a problem though.